# Как получить фото с thispersondoesntnotexists

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, bs4

Пытаюсь получить фото через python отправив запрос, но на выходе получаю непонятный текст:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который использую для отправки запроса:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'accept': 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'cookie: SL_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp=1; SL_wptGlobTipTmp=1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.40'
}

print(requests.get('https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?').text)
```

Могли бы подсказать, что я делаю неправильно и как могу получить новое сгенерированное фото?

Comment: В вашем случае можно сказать так: что хотели то и получили)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На вид это `JPEG`, судя по сигнатуре `JFIF`. Просто возьмите `.content` от ответа сервера (а не `.text`) и сохраните его в файл. Только не забудьте открыть файл на запись в двоичном режиме, а не стандартном текстовом.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Можно так]

Пробуйте искать в интернете, и читать документацию.